# Data-view is not updating when entity is updated in Mendix

Tags: mendix

Question is: How to show data in data-view in such a way that if entity is updated some how dataview is updated too.

This is my Entity named `latestReading`.

[image]

Here is my page `LatestReading` that show latest readings. It contains three data views.

[image]

This page is not called directly, as it expect a object `latestReading`. Hence a micro-flow named `showLatestReadingPage` is executed that fetches or create `latestReading` object  and pass it to the `LatestReading` page and display `LatestReading` page.

Here is that micro-flow.

[image]

`getOrCreateLatestReading` is a micro-flow that returns us the a `latestReading` object if it is available or create a new `latestReading` object if it is not already created and then returns it.

Here is that micro-flow.

[image]

These are the properties of first of the three data-views in `LatestReading` page as shown diagram of `LatestReading` Page above. Name of this DataView is `TemperatureDataView`

[image]

These are the properties of text widget that is inside `TemperatureDataView` data-view. Its name is `temperatureText`. It shows value of temperature in the `TemperatureDataView`.

[image]

And this is the caption of `temperatureText` text widget:

[image]

Problem is when another micro-flow updates the value of `latestReading` the text widget is not updated. I need to reload it by clicking on navigation link of `LatestReading` page again.

I need my text widget in data view to keep updating value of `latestReading` when it is updated my some other micro-flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that ‘refresh in client’ only works if the microflow is executed in the same context as the page (client) that the user is seeing. For example if there is a button on the page that triggers a microflow that refreshes the client then it will update the widget. However, if the microflow is triggered by the system (e.g. a scheduled event) then these changes are in a different context. Also if another user triggers a refresh it will only refresh that user’s client. Also if one user is logged in through multiple browsers (i.e. has multiple sessions, it also means that for each session there is a different user context.

The simplest solution in this case would likely be to use an appstore  widget that periodically triggers a refresh on the object displayed in the dataview, such as this one: https://appstore.home.mendix.com/link/app/27/ . Simply create nanoflow or microflow with a change action that changes no attributes but refreshes the object.

Comment: To improve the the answer, both nanoflow and microflow must return a boolean "true" and have an input parameter (object from the dataview). When using microflow, a "Change Object" activity with setting only the "Refresh in client" action to "Yes" is enough ( no need to commit, so  "Commit" action can remain "No" ). For nanoflow the "Change Object" action has only one option "Commit" which must be ticked.  That's why I suspect using a microflow might be better, since no commit is needed. I've tested it on a simple persistable entity (with no association).